# How use TalendDate in context variable

Tags: talend

[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIHAA.png)
How can I run this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have talend function defined in the contexts. Rather you have to include the functions while calling the context variables.

Create a context having the path --> ttratta

Call the context and append the date function as below,

[image]